# Linq extension methods for each Linq provider

Tags: c#, linq, expression, expression-trees

I am engaged in a project which is Linq provider agnostic. So, it means we're able to work with whichever Linq provider we want (at least, in theory).

We've implemented our Linq provider in order to be able to get information from our server.

We've created some Linq Extension methods for providing facilities. For example:

```
public static Expression<Func<TElementType, bool>> MetaInfo<TElementType>(this Expression<Func<TElementType, TElementType>> expr, string metaInfo)
{
    Type entityType = typeof(TElementType);
    PropertyInfo collectionPropertyInfo = entityType.GetProperty("Metainfos"); // TODO: Pick the property up instead of using a literal string
    if (collectionPropertyInfo == null)
        throw new MissingFieldException(string.Format("{0} collection doesn't appear in {1}", "MetaInfos", entityType));

    Type collGenericType = collectionPropertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();
    if (!collGenericType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Domain.MetaInfoValue)))
        throw new TypeLoadException(string.Format("Collection generic type doesn't inherit from {1}", collGenericType));

    ParameterExpression entityParameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "t");
    ParameterExpression metaInfoParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(collGenericType, "m");

    MemberExpression collectionMemberExpression = Expression.Property(entityParameter, collectionPropertyInfo);
    MethodInfo anyMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name.Equals("Any") && m.GetParameters().Length == 2).Single().MakeGenericMethod(collGenericType);

    LambdaExpression innerCondition = Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.GetDelegateType(collGenericType, typeof(bool)),
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(metaInfoParameterExpression, "Key"),
            Expression.Constant(metaInfo)
        ),
        metaInfoParameterExpression
    );

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElementType, bool>>(
        Expression.Call(anyMethod, collectionMemberExpression, innerCondition),
        entityParameter
        );
    }
```

So, this extension method builds an `Expression` is injected to main Linq sentence.

The problem is some of these methods generates incompatible expression that some providers aren't able to handle, or return different results.

We would like to provide custom extension methods according to each Linq provider and generate the correct expression.

The problem is extension methods are `static methods in static classes`... How could I generate custom implementations of these `static methods of static classes`?

**EDIT**

Use example:

```
this.backend.DigitalInputs
    .Where(                                       
        LinqTreeExtensions.Query<Backend.Domain.DigitalInput>(di => di)                                               
        .Field<Backend.Domain.DigitalInput, string>("Matter")
        .EndsWith("v")
     );
```

Where `LinqExtensions.Query<T>` is:

```
public static Expression<Func<TElementType, TElementType>> Query<TElementType>(this Expression<Func<TElementType, TElementType>> expr)
    {
        return expr;
    }
```

and `Field` function:

```
    public static Expression<Func<TElementType, TReturnType>> Field<TElementType, TReturnType>(this Expression<Func<TElementType, TElementType>> expr, string field)
    {
        Type entityType = typeof(TElementType);
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = entityType.GetProperty(field);
        if (propertyInfo == null)
            throw new MissingFieldException(string.Format("{0} field doesn't exist on {1}", field, entityType));

        ParameterExpression parameterExpression = expr.Parameters.First();
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElementType, TReturnType>>(
            Expression.Property(parameterExpression, propertyInfo),
            parameterExpression
        );
    }
```

Comment: How is this extension method used?

Comment: I've added a sample on post.

Comment: ??? your example does not explain what are your intentions. If you want a query provider agnostic chanable expression extension method, then there are 2 things you should be careful about:
1. make sure your method does not make it to the tree, e.g. it is always called, and never added to the tree. The latter might happen for example when you use asqueeruable on a collection, and then use your method on the parameter lambda
2. you will always have to call expression.Provider.CreateQuery, so that the returned expression tree uses still the original provider.